# How to carry out save action on a page when the user presses the start key

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app and want to save data from a page each time the user navigates away from the page. This works fine if the user presses the back key or navigates within the application, however if I press the start key nothing is saved. My code is shown below:

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        if (!toDelete)
        {
            List<NoteItem> ni = this.getNoteItems();
            await SaveNotes(ni, this.Title.Text);
        }
    }
```

This calls the method to save the notes. I don't see any other events on a page to save this. Does anybody know where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try handling this case in App.xaml.cs.

When the Start button is pressed, Application_Deactivated event is raised.

For example

```
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //do the saving here
}
```

Although, I'm getting the OnNavigatingFrom event called when pressing Start button, too, so it may be the charm of using await in event handlers. Read [this article by Andy Wigley](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/07/31/beware-the-perils-of-async-await-in-application-lifecycle-event-handlers-in-fact-in-any-event-handlers.aspx), it's packed with useful info.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did think about that, I just was not sure how to get access to all of the data from my pages to then run the save from there. I thought I should be getting that event when pressing the start button so will have to check if I have broken anything else.

Comment: @DaveGreen Do you not get the event raised, or the stuff just isn't saved?

Comment: the event is being raised but the data was not being saved, I have stepped through the problem and it appears that the method was ending and not waiting for the await SaveNotes to complete. I have just added a clause to check the work is complete until I can figure out why this happens. Thanks for the article link, I am going through that now to improve what I was doing.